# Screen blacks out when simulating left click

Tags: c++, winapi, keypress

I'm learning how to use SendInput() and I've come across a problem. Whenever I try to simulate a left click, the screen always blacks out. Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void MouseLeftClick(){
    INPUT ip;

    ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));


    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void PressKey(int keyCode){
    INPUT ip;

    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    ip.ki.wVk = keyCode;

    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;

    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));


    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main(){
    while (true){
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)){
            MouseLeftClick();
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

It also doesn't happen when I simulate a key press.

Comment: Nothing of the sort happened when I tested the code. It worked as expected.

Comment: You aren't initializing all the fields on the struct. It's also a mistake to send one event at a time. Batch them up as the documentation makes clear.

Comment: Passing `1` as the first argument to `SendInput`, and then calling it twice in a row is **always** wrong. Consider reading the [documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ZeroMemory(&ip, sizeof(ip));` after the line `INPUT ip;` will solve your problem.

Comment: C and C++ provide a convenient syntax for initializing structures: `INPUT ip = { 0 };`